# Get debugging metadata for Xamarin Android Bundles?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, google-play

I've Googled this quite a bit and found only that, as of around a year ago Xamarin does not generate debugging information for Android App Bundles. I have an App in the Play Store and it's being beta tested by a customer and the exceptions that are logged are less than ideal for finding the actual problem area.
Is there any way to get decent debugging data in an Android Bundle?
Seems like it would be a pretty important thing as the Play Store does not accept APKs.

Comment: Microsoft's answer is to use MS AppCenter. I assume they manage symbols there.

Comment: Thanks! I am looking into it. Does it have a store where people can download it?